# Vote count totals are cropped on review pages

Tags: bug

Today, I noticed that the vote review totals are being cut off in the display.

Like here, for example, noting the red outlined area:

[image]

What changed and what can be done to fix this?

I've tested this on a couple of machines and the behavior was found to be consistent across the machines even after clearing cookie/cache data.

I am using Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.04.1).

In Firefox 21, the vote total count is completely cropped out and not visible at all.

Comment: Works fine on Chromium here for me.

Comment: Hmmm ... this was supposedly fixed recently.

Comment: @FEichinger It looks like these pages started rendering properly, for me, about 12 hours ago